# Run Unity standalone in Headless Mode whilst capturing screenshots

Tags: unity, rendering, camera, rendertexture

I need to create a unity project which runs in Headless mode (using the -batchmode command), but it must capture screenshots e.g. every one second and write them out to a file.

I understand that in headless mode you need to forcefully call Camera.Render() in order for anything to be rendered.

It seems that time freezes after the first screenshot is captured. The first screenshot looks absolutely correct, but all subsequent screenshots are identical to the first, implying that time has frozen.

What do I need to do to ensure that the scene updates correctly over time and that the camera is able to render every second?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets
{
    public class Particles : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private const float screenshotEvery = 1.0f;
        private float timerCount = 0f;
        private float elapsedSecond;
        private const float maxElapsedSecond = 20;
        private string screenshotsDirectory = "UnityHeadlessRenderingScreenshots";
        public Camera camOV;
        public RenderTexture currentRT;

        // Use this for initialization
        public void Start ()
        {
            Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
            if (Directory.Exists(screenshotsDirectory))
            {
                Directory.Delete(screenshotsDirectory, true);
            }
            if (!Application.isEditor)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(screenshotsDirectory);
                camOV.targetTexture = currentRT;
            }

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        public void Update ()
        {
            elapsedSecond += Time.deltaTime;
            timerCount += Time.deltaTime;
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (elapsedSecond <= maxElapsedSecond)
            {
                if (timerCount >= screenshotEvery)
                {
                    TakeScreenShot();
                    timerCount = 0f;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Quit();
            }
        }

        public void TakeScreenShot()
        {
            RenderTexture.active = camOV.targetTexture;
            camOV.Render();
            Texture2D imageOverview = new Texture2D(camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            imageOverview.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
            imageOverview.Apply();
            RenderTexture.active = currentRT;

            // Encode texture into PNG
            byte[] bytes = imageOverview.EncodeToPNG();

            // save in memory
            string filename = elapsedSecond + ".png";
            var path = screenshotsDirectory + "/" + filename;
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);

        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

---

Update:

Attaching code from where we left this - we haven't spent much time on this since I initially posted this question (hence why much of the code below is commented out!) Managed to get it to work in the end - there was a bug with particle systems causing them to not render correctly in headless mode. This should work with 2017.2 at least.

Our issue now is that the performance of this is so bad - struggling to capture above 60fps for 1920x1080 due to the fact that copying data from the GPU to the CPU for processing is so slow. If anyone has any ideas on this, I would be very grateful!

```
        public void Start()
    {
        //Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
        foreach (Display display in Display.displays)
        {
            display.SetParams(display.systemWidth, display.systemHeight, 10000, 0);
        }

        camOV.forceIntoRenderTexture = true;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        timerCount += Time.deltaTime;

    }

    public void OnPostRender()
    {
        TakeScreenShot();
    }

    public void TakeScreenShot()
    {

        //RenderTexture.active = camOV.targetTexture;
        camOV.Render();
        resultantImage = new Texture2D(camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

        resultantImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
        Graphics.CopyTexture(camOV.targetTexture, resultantImage);
        resultantImage.Apply();

    }

    public void ReadPixelsOut(string filename)
    { 

        screenshotCount += 1;
        //IntPtr.Add(resultantImage.GetNativeTexturePtr(), 10);
        textureToUpdate.UpdateTexture(resultantImage.GetNativeTexturePtr(), 3, camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height);

        //Color[] color = resultantImage.GetPixels();

        RenderTexture.active = camOV.targetTexture;
        Debug.Log("Get Pixels Called");
        numberOfTimesGetPixelsCalled += 1;
        // Encode texture into PNG
        //byte[] bytes = resultantImage.EncodeToPNG();
        // save on disk
        //var path = screenshotsDirectory + "/" + filename;
        //File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);

        Destroy(resultantImage);

        //camOV.targetTexture.DiscardContents();
        //camOV.targetTexture.Release();
        //GL.Clear(true, true, Color.green, 1f);
        //GL.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to do the same import FBX into scene and then export PNG from screen capture using its camera.
Did you ever get far with your app? And is there a project you can share? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Greg, to answer your question; we ended up not continuing down this route for the time being, and abandoned this. We discovered that the images WERE being captured correctly, but that there was a bug with particle systems such that they do not render beyond the first frame in headless mode. This was sorted by Unity. The issue we found was that capturing was far too slow because data had to be copied back from the GPU to the CPU for processing to be done, making it CPU bound. It would JUST manage 1080p @60fps. I have attached our (messy) debug code.

Comment: Your original problem was described as "capture screenshots e.g. every one second" but now you're talking about 60 fps — have your needs changed? Are you looking for a way to stream/record gameplay video in realtime, rather than a a way to save periodic frames as images? (It might seem like the former "should" just be a matter of doing the latter really fast, but in practice different techniques are used for streaming solutions)

Comment: Have you tried running it headless Ben? Because in headless all I get is grey image. I have a similar script that works very fast while using unity UI. However in headless I get nothing but grey image. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: @BenHayward Please avoid posting these questions as answers, that's not what they're for: answers should answer the question. Please take part in the site to get [enough rep (50)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to be able to add comment to others questions. Alternatively, you can try to [ask another question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if your issue is different.